# Show which command failed

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

`command1 && command2 && echo "OK" || echo "FAIL"`

This will print `OK` if both commands succeeded or `FAIL` if either of commands failed.

How can I modify this to print:

- `OK` if both commands succeded,
- `FAIL 1` if `command1` failed, and
- `FAIL 2` if `command2` failed?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, for example:

```
if ! command1; then
    echo 'FAIL 1'
elif ! command2; then
    echo 'FAIL 2'
else
    echo 'OK'
fi
```

If the point is just to quickly debug a Bash script consider using the `-x` option:

> Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Using curly braces to group commands (without creating a subshell) will work:

```
command1 && { command2 && echo OK || echo FAIL2 } || echo FAIL1
```

Note that if `command1` fails, `command2` won’t be run so you’ll just get `FAIL1`.

I also think that this construction is not very readable. I find using `&&` works well for simple cases but for more complicated conditionals, I prefer to use `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a variable (`a`) and write only at the end which was the failed command

```
 a=1 && cmd2 && a=2 && cmd1 && a=0 && echo ok || echo fail $a
```

You can use that value later in the script... 
for this reason after the last command you can reset the value to 0.

not elegant but somehow it works. :-)